# Condtional String_Agg In Azure SQL

Tags: azure-sql-database, sql-server-2017

I have a table of `Points`.

```
CREATE TABLE Points(
ID int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
Label varchar(50) NULL,
Destination bit NOT NULL,
PickUp bit NOT NULL,
SetDown bit NOT NULL)
)
```

With Data like:

```
| ID | Label      | PickUp | SetDown | Destination |
|----|------------|--------|---------|-------------|
| 1  | Seattle    | 1      |         |             |
| 2  | Denver     | 1      |         |             |
| 3  | Restaurant |        | 1       | 1           |
| 4  | Dave's     | 1      |         |             |
| 5  | Cindy's    | 1      |         |             |
| 6  | Airport    | 1      | 1       |             |
| 7  | School     |        |         | 1           |
```

And a parent many-to-many table, call it `PointParent`

```
CREATE TABLE PointParent(
ID int NOT NULL,
PointID int NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Points(ID)
)
```

with data like:

```
| ID | PointID |
|----|---------|
| 1  | 1       |
| 1  | 2       |
| 1  | 3       |
| 2  | 4       |
| 2  | 5       |
| 2  | 6       |
| 2  | 7       |
```

I'm writing a view to summarize the labels of the points, grouped by the parent id:

```
SELECT PointParent.ID, String_Agg(Label, ', ') AS Summary 
FROM Points LEFT OUTER JOIN PointParent ON Points.ID = PointParent.PointID 
GROUP BY PointParent.ID
```

Now, I need to extend this concept and summarize the label for all points that have `PickUp = 1`, then another summary for those that have `SetDown = 1`, and another for `Destination = 1`, all grouped by the `PointParent.ID`.

The way I'm accomplishing this now is with three subqueries:

```
SELECT PointParent.ID, PickUp.Summary AS PickUpSummary, SetDown.Summary AS SetDownSummary, 
Destination.Summary AS DestinationSummary 
FROM PointParent LEFT OUTER JOIN (
  SELECT PointParent.ID, String_Agg(Label, ', ') AS Summary 
  FROM Points LEFT OUTER JOIN PointParent ON Points.ID = PointParent.PointID
  WHERE PickUp = 1 
  GROUP BY PointParent.ID) 
AS PickUp ON PickUp.ID = PointParent.ID LEFT OUTER JOIN (
  SELECT PointParent.ID, String_Agg(Label, ', ') AS Summary 
  FROM Points LEFT OUTER JOIN PointParent ON Points.ID = PointParent.PointID 
  WHERE SetDown = 1 
  GROUP BY PointParent.ID)
AS SetDown ON SetDown.ID = PointParent.ID LEFT OUTER JOIN (
  SELECT PointParent.ID, String_Agg(Label, ', ') AS Summary 
  FROM Points LEFT OUTER JOIN PointParent ON Points.ID = PointParent.PointID 
  WHERE Destination = 1 
  GROUP BY PointParent.ID) 
AS Destination ON Destination.ID = PointParent.ID
```

Which produces results like:

```
| ID | PickUpSummary            | SetDownSummary | DestinationSummary |
|----|--------------------------|----------------|--------------------|
| 1  | Seattle, Denver          | Restaurant     | Restaurant         |
| 2  | Dave's, Cindy's, Airport | Airport        | School             |
```

Is there a way to achieve this without having three separate subqueries?  Some way to aggregate all three strings in a single pass over the table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a single table access (about half the estimated cost).

```
SELECT pp.ID, 
  PickUpSummary      = STRING_AGG(CASE p.Pickup      WHEN 1 THEN p.Label END, ', '),
  SetDownSummary     = STRING_AGG(CASE p.SetDown     WHEN 1 THEN p.Label END, ', '),
  DestinationSummary = STRING_AGG(CASE p.Destination WHEN 1 THEN p.Label END, ', ')
FROM dbo.PointParent AS pp
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Points AS p
ON pp.PointID = p.ID
GROUP BY pp.ID;
```

An index on `PointParent (ID, PointID)` - which will eliminate a sort operation - will fare even better.

Comment: Ahah, CASE inside of STRING_AGG!  Looking at the docs, it does say <expression>, so that could be arbitrarily complex.   CASE returns a null when not matched and STRING_AGG ignores nulls - profit!